# How to remove ban of 320 7a

Tags: customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, deception

I had a ban of 320 7a under paragraph 245. I had a bank account but my consultant used a fake bank statement in 2010 for student visa. Now how can I remove my ban?

Comment: What country, please?

Comment: How long was the ban? 10 years is typical and if that applies to you, you might find your best option is to wait 2 more years. Do you think you could qualify without lying on your next application?

Comment: What country are you applying to (for those of us who don't memorize paragraph numbers). What is your nationality? What is the reason you want to apply for another visa? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: ECMComment:I am satisfied that the ECO correctly applied 320(7A) of the Immigration Rules to your case in light of the fact that non-genuine documentation was provided.Furthermore, as your application has been refused under 320(7A) it is also hereby refused under paragraph 245ZV(a) of the Immigration Rules.You should note that because this application for entry clearance has been refused under paragraph 320 (7A) of the Immigration Rules, any future applications may also be refused under paragraph 320 (7B) of the Immigration Rules (subject to the requirements set out in paragraph 320 (7C)

Comment: This is the mail which I got and I m from Pakistan and father is uk national bt I have a ban and he never send a single penny to us from last 25 years and I m 34 years old so how can I come there

Answer (score 4):

You have been banned *because you lied*. Not just because your bank accounts were unsatisfactory. So even if the bank accounts look better now, the fact remains that *you lied.* Even if the ban is over there is no guarantee that you will get a visa.